# Consulta en PostgreSQL para retornar información de acuerdo a fechas

Tags: sql, postgresql

Buen día,
estoy en proceso de aprendizaje de SQL y necesito ayuda con algo que no entiendo, estría altamente agradecido si alguien me puede ayudar.

El problema radica en que necesito retornar toda la informacion de un registro y una de sus clausulas es que la edad debe ser entre 30 y 70 años, esta clausula es la que me tiene atascado puesto que no entiendo el concepto de como obtener esa edad ya que el dato: fecha de nacimiento en la tabla aparece en formato `dd/mm/aaaa` ejemplo: 12/09/1990, se que debo usar el current_date pero no se como conformar la instruccion, si usar el to_char.

Basicamente lo que me hace falta es la clausula de que los pasajeros deben tener entre 30 y 70 años.

---

```
Select * fom pasajero
where length (nommbre)>5
and ..... (innstruccion faltante)
```

---

Adjunto dcreacion de las tablas e insert de los datos:

```
create table pasajero (
cod_pas numeric(8) constraint pk_pasajero primary key,
nombre varchar(40) constraint nn_pasajero not null,
ciudad_nacimiento varchar(20),
fecha_nac date,
telefono varchar(20)
);

insert into pasajero values (1,'luis','cali','05/03/1988','6555555');
insert into pasajero values (2,'luisa','bogota','15/06/1975','6333333');
insert into pasajero values (3,'rosalba','bogota','04/03/1970','6444444');
insert into pasajero values (4,'emilson','pereira','23/11/1982','6222222');
insert into pasajero values (5,'estela','cali','01/12/1965','6111111');
insert into pasajero values (6,'raul','bucaramanga','16/07/1970','6666666');
insert into pasajero values (7,'nestor','cali','29/03/1960','6777777');
insert into pasajero values (8,'ruben','bucaramanga','28/05/1973','6888888');
insert into pasajero values (9,'dario','ibague','22/03/1955','6999999');
insert into pasajero values (10,'alberto','cartagena','26/07/1966','6444455');
insert into pasajero values (11,'adriana','bucaramanga','28/06/1977','6444466');
insert into pasajero values (12,'erika','cali','24/08/1957','6444477');
insert into pasajero values (13,'luis','medellin','14/10/1990','6444433');
insert into pasajero values (14,'ramiro','medellin','22/04/1989','6444422');
insert into pasajero values (15,'reynaldo','barranquilla','01/03/1992','6444411');
insert into pasajero values (16,'dario','bucaramanga','28/06/1977','6564466');
insert into pasajero values (17,'martha','cali','24/08/1957','6445611');
insert into pasajero values (18,'luis','bogota','14/12/1977','6444400');
insert into pasajero values (19,'adriana','medellin','22/02/1983','6444456');
insert into pasajero values (20,'roso','barranquilla','01/05/1990','6445611');
insert into pasajero values (21,'ramon','cali','07/03/1978','6555665');
insert into pasajero values (22,'sneyder','bogota','14/06/1985','6366333');
insert into pasajero values (23,'estela','bogota','24/03/1990','6449944');
insert into pasajero values (24,'edith','pereira','13/11/1992','6228822');
insert into pasajero values (25,'ester','cali','11/12/1995','6111811');
insert into pasajero values (26,'raulito','bucaramanga','26/07/1980','6688666');
insert into pasajero values (27,'napo','cali','19/03/1980','6777457');
insert into pasajero values (28,'rodolfo','bucaramanga','18/05/1983','6848988');
insert into pasajero values (29,'damian','ibague','02/03/1985','6993399');
insert into pasajero values (30,'albert','cartagena','06/07/1986','6433455');
insert into pasajero values (31,'ariana','bucaramanga','18/06/1997','6443366');
insert into pasajero values (32,'erick','cali','14/08/1997','6441277');
insert into pasajero values (33,'luis','medellin','14/10/1980','6441333');
insert into pasajero values (34,'ranses','medellin','12/04/1979','6443822');
insert into pasajero values (35,'rey','barranquilla','01/03/1982','6394411');
insert into pasajero values (36,'oliva','bucaramanga','18/06/1987','6560066');
insert into pasajero values (37,'martha','cali','04/08/1987','6445001');
insert into pasajero values (38,'olivo','bogota','24/12/1987','6409400');
insert into pasajero values (39,'anita','medellin','12/02/1963','6490456');
insert into pasajero values (40,'rosario','barranquilla','21/05/1980','6407611');
```

Estoy trabajando sobre PostgreSQL. Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Puedes apoyarte en [este tema de alguna página](https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/PostgreSQL/1430531-manejo-de-fechas.html) para ver cómo podrías hacerlo. Cuando tengas una pregunta más concreta con gusto se te apoya.

Comment: Amigo, el estilo de fecha no es compatible con PostgreSQL 9.6 ni 9.3, de hecho, es compatible con SQLite, puedes verificar eso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la funcion **age** de postgreSQL para calcular los años

```
Select * ,age(current_Date ,fecha_nac) from pasajero
 where length(nombre) >5
 and age(current_Date ,fecha_nac) between '30 years' and '70 years'
```